# How to trace L2 packet in linux kernel bridge and interface?

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel, packet, ftrace

I create a Linux bridge and add two virtual interface to this bridge.

```
ip link add br0 address 01:02:03:04:00:00 type bridge
ip link add veth0 address 01:02:03:04:00:10 type dummy
ip link add veth1 address 01:02:03:04:00:20 type dummy

ip link set dev veth0 master br0
ip link set dev veth1 master br0

ip link set br0 up
ip link set veth0 up
ip link set veth1 up
```

Then write a raw socket listening program that bind the veth0.

```
socket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))

struct sockaddr_ll sockaddr;
memset(&sockaddr, 0x0, sizeof(sockaddr));
sockaddr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
sockaddr.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
sockaddr.sll_pkttype = PACKET_OUTGOING;

sockaddr.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("veth0");
bind(socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr, sizeof(sockaddr)
```

Then write a sender program that same way created as the listener, using veth1 interface. That program send eth frame.

```
struct ethhdr_frame* eth_packet;
eth_packet->h_dest = "01:02:03:04:00:10" //it not string, just show purpose
eth_packet->h_source = "01:02:03:04:00:20"
eth_packet->h_proto = 0x88b5
eth_packet->payload = "hello world!"
```

Now my problem is listener can't capture eth frame which is send by my sender. To find where is my packet dropped, I used ftrace filtered by br*, but even any bridge handler function wasn't call.

```
$cd /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
$echo br* > set_ftrace_filter
$echo function_graph > current_tracer
$echo 1 > tracing_on ; ./my_sender ; echo 0 > tracing_on
```

Comment: what is def of ethhdr_frame?

Comment: @stark 
struct ethhdr_frame {
    unsigned char h_dest[6]; 
    unsigned char h_source[6];
    __be16  h_proto;
    char payload[];
};

Comment: you cant assign a string literal to an array, and an array cannot have an indefinite size.

Comment: @stark yes i know, i put this line just explain purpose. In real code binary take a few argument like dst address, bind interface name, than parse and convert suitable formats ........ I don't want to show unnecessary stuff right here.

Comment: there is not enough information to determine your error. Please show a [mre] including the frame checksum.

Comment: @stark ok. I am sharing github link. https://github.com/shun-yo/cethping